# Use of 'nicematrix' for matrices with special annotations

Tags: amsmath, nicematrix

I generated the following image using `nicematrix`. 
Everything works fine; so there is no urgent problem at the moment.

**Note**: *The result or optics is exactly as desired. In the following I am only concerned with a few subtleties of the code, for optimal use of the nicematrix-package.*

[image]

However, out of personal interest, I would have been interested in 2 things:

1. *`"A1 A2 ... A4"` should be centered vertically to the whole.* 
   Is my use of 
   `\Block{2-1}{A1} & \Block{2-1}{A2} & \Block{2-1}{\cdots} & \Block{2-1}{A4}    ...  \\`  
   okay here? 
   Or should I have done better in the sense of `nicematrix.sty`?
2. *Above and below of `"A1 A2 ... A4"` I added vertical lines, each to the ends of the matrix.* 
   For the *lower lines* I had to make a visual adjustment: 
   `\draw[`**`shorten <=1em+2pt`**`] (2-\col) -- (last-|\col.5);` 
   This means that if the content changes, adjustments will probably be necessary again. 
   Could this possibly be made more stable/flexible?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
$M=\begin{NiceArray}{(c c c c)  c  (c c c c)}
   &   &   &   &   \Block{*-1}{\cdot}  & B1 &    &            &   \\
\Block{2-1}{A1} & \Block{2-1}{A2} & \Block{2-1}{\cdots} & \Block{2-1}{A4} 
        &                                        &    & B2  &   &   \\
   &   &    &    &                             &     &    &  \ddots &   \\
   &   &   &   &                              &     &    &            & B4
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
% Verticals  =====================
\foreach \col in {1,2,4}{%% 
\draw[shorten <=0pt] (2-\col) -- (1-|\col.5) ; 
\draw[shorten <=1em+2pt] (2-\col) -- (last-|\col.5) ; 
}%%
\end{tikzpicture}
% Underbracing  =================
\UnderBrace[yshift=2pt]{4-6}{4-9}{=X}
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the baseline where you want you can use the option `baseline=<row number>` for the `NiceArray`. But that requires the `A1` to be in its own row, not in a block. One possibility is to make your array with 5 rows and 10 columns. Then in the "second" array use a 2 by 2 `Block` for `\ddots`.

[image]

Other changes:

- place a thin space (`\,`) to the right and left of the `\cdot` column so that the spacing is the same as if you used two separate arrays.
- make a new style (`myline` in the code below) to shorten the vertical lines. Since `A1`, `A2`, etc. are in their own cells, the spacing is even.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\tikzset{myline/.style={shorten <=3pt}}
\begin{document}
$M=\begin{NiceArray}{(cccc)!\,c!\,(ccccc)}[baseline=3]
 & & & & \Block{*-1}{\cdot} & B1\\
 & & & & & & B2 \\
A1 & A2 & \cdots & A4 & & & & \Block{2-2}{\ddots} \\
 \\
 & & & & & & & & & B4
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
% Verticals  =====================
\foreach \col in {1,2,4}{%%  
  \draw[myline] (3-\col) -- (1-|\col.5) ; 
  \draw[myline] (3-\col) -- (last-|\col.5) ; 
}%%
\end{tikzpicture}
% Underbracing  =================
\UnderBrace[yshift=2pt]{5-6}{5-10}{=X}
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand. Very nice. ;)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

If you want the lines to remain below `"A1 A2 ... A4"`, then you need to use `\tikzmarknode` from `tikzmark` library

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \setlength{\arraycolsep}{1em}
        \smash{\rlap{\rule{11cm}{0.1pt}}}
        M
        =
        \begin{NiceArray}{(c c c c)  c  (c c c c)}
            \CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
            \Body
            &   &   &   &   \Block{*-1}{\cdot}  & B1 &    &            &   \\
            \Block{2-1}{\tikzmarknode{A1}{A1}} & \Block{2-1}{\tikzmarknode{A2}{A2}} & \Block{2-1}{\cdots} & \Block{2-1}{\tikzmarknode{A4}{A4}} 
            &                                        &    & B2  &   &   \\
            &   &    &    &                             &     &    &  \ddots &   \\
            &   &   &   &                              &     &    &            & B4
            \CodeAfter
            \begin{tikzpicture}[]
                
                % Verticals  =====================
                \draw[shorten <=1pt] (A1.north) -- (1-|1.5);
                \draw[shorten <=1pt] (A2.north) -- (1-|2.5); 
                \draw[shorten <=1pt] (A4.north) -- (1-|4.5);
                
                \draw[shorten >=1pt] (last-|1.5) -- (A1.south); 
                \draw[shorten >=1pt] (last-|2.5) -- (A2.south);
                \draw[shorten >=1pt] (last-|4.5) -- (A4.south);
                    
            \end{tikzpicture}
            % Underbracing  =================
            \UnderBrace[yshift=2pt]{4-6}{4-9}{=X}
        \end{NiceArray}
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```